# Small tweak to my c++ pyramid assignment? How should I do it?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I was tasked with this problem for homework for my `c++` class and I can't figure it out.

The task is: `Create a program that will create a pattern in which is a pyramid. The user should enter the maximum number of rows to be output. Use a while loop that confirms the number of rows is between 1 and 9 inclusive. Next 1 should be output in the first row, 222 output in the second row, 33333 should be output in the third row, etc. For example if the user entered 7 the following would be output.`

The code I have now does this almost exactly, instead of outputting, for example 222 for the second row, it outputs 2 2
Here is what my code looks like:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rows, count = 0, count1 = 0, k = 0;
    cout << "Please enter the number of rows." << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    while (rows > 9)
    {
        cout << "That is an invalid selection, please choose up to 9 rows." << endl;
        cin >> rows;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int space = 1; space <= rows - i; ++space)
        {
            cout << " ";
            ++count;
        }
        while (k != 2 * i - 1)
        {
            if (count <= rows - 1)
            {
                cout << i << " ";
                ++count;
            }
            k++;
        }
        count1 = count = k = 0;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm assuming it should just be a small tweak.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Take a closer look at this line `cout << i << " ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This loop

```
    while (k != 2 * i - 1)
    {
        if (count <= rows - 1)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            ++count;
        }
        k++;
    }
    count1 = count = k = 0;
```

does not make sense. For example the variable `count1` is never used except the statement

```
    count1 = count = k = 0;
```

So it is unclear what is the purpose to define this variable.

Using manipulators from the header `<iomanip>` you can write a pyramid using only one loop.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        const int MAX_HEIGHT = 9;

        std::cout << "Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than "
                  << MAX_HEIGHT << " (0 - exit): ";

        int height;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> height ) or ( height <= 0 ) ) break;

        if ( MAX_HEIGHT < height ) height = MAX_HEIGHT;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for ( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( height - i ) << std::setfill( ' ' ) << i + 1;
            std::cout << std::setw( 2 * i + 1 ) << std::setfill( char( i + '1' ) ) << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look the following way

```
Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 2

 1
222

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 3

  1
 222
33333

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 4

   1
  222
 33333
4444444

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 5

    1
   222
  33333
 4444444
555555555

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 6

     1
    222
   33333
  4444444
 555555555
66666666666

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 7

      1
     222
    33333
   4444444
  555555555
 66666666666
7777777777777

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 8

       1
      222
     33333
    4444444
   555555555
  66666666666
 7777777777777
888888888888888

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 9

        1
       222
      33333
     4444444
    555555555
   66666666666
  7777777777777
 888888888888888
99999999999999999

Enter the height of a pyramid not greater than 9 (0 - exit): 0
```